# Camera not listed under Privacy settings since upgrade to macOS Sierra

Tags: remote-desktop, camera, privacy

I recently started working from home on my Mac by connecting to Microsoft Remote Desktop from my PC at this office. My problem is when using Skype or Microsoft Teams in the remote session, no camera is found.

My Mac built-in camera works well - I tried Facetime, messenger and photo booth.

I have checked the remote desktop settings: the camera device box is ticked to be used in the remote sessions.

However I have checked my Mac Privacy settings, and Camera is not listed in the options, which means I can't control which app or website can use it.

Note: I tried adding apps that use camera in Accessibility but that was useless.
Note 2: I recently upgraded to macOS Sierra 10.12.6 and might have "lost" it at that time.

So my question is: how can I add Camera under Privacy?

Unless there is another way to allow my Mac built-in camera to be use in my Microsoft remote session?

[image: lack of options under Privacy settings]

Answer (score 1):

*Do you have already tried a restart?*

Very special. Normally there should also be "camera" to control the release of the camera.

Like this:
[image]

I would reload **macOS Sierra 10.12.6** on your Mac, I have never seen anything like it...

Hopefully it will work soon ...